# Order by on List Binding

Tags: sapui5

I'm building a mobile app using OpenUI5 and Cordova. This app consumes OData services and I'm listing some entities using `sap.m.List` on an XML view page. I wonder if there is any property to order the list by some field or at least a way to include this functionality in the controller.

Could someone give me a hint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the online [documentation](https://sap.github.io/openui5-docs/#/Sorting,_Grouping,_and_Filtering_for_List_Binding_ec79a5d) about Sorter definition. For example, the following list has a ProductCollection and is sorted by SupplierName with descending order and grouping.

```xml
<List items="{
  path: '/ProductCollection',
  sorter: {
    path: 'SupplierName',
    descending: true,
    group: true
  }
}" />
```